# How to free memory after strsep()?

Tags: c, memory-management

I wrote this function:

```
char** parse_parameters(const char* input_string, int num_params, char** params) {
    char *temp_string = strdup(input_string);
    char **pp;
    for (pp = params; (*pp = strsep(&temp_string, ";")) != NULL;) {
        if (**pp == '\0')
            break;
        pp++;
        if (pp >= &params[num_params])
            break;
    }
    free(temp_string);
    return params;
}
```

Which I'm using like this:

```
char *parameters[3];
parse_parameters("some;delimited;string", 3, parameters);
```

From my understanding inside `parameters` array I am pointing to memory which was already freed. But if I don't free inside `parse_parameters` function I have a memory leak. How should I solve this?

Comment: How is `parameters` initialized ?

Comment: if (pp >= &params[num_params]) isn't that a strange comparison

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options:

1. Leave it to the caller to free `params[0]` and clearly state this in the documentation for the function.
2. Remove the `const` from `input_string` and do the work in place. If the caller want to keep an unchanged copy the caller has to make a copy before calling the function.
3. The caller has to provide a buffer that is at least as large as temp_string to be used as working area (extra parameter to `parse_parameters`). You copy the string there.